# Find the value of $\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i+\dots}}}$ .

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Find the value of $\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i+\dots}}}$ ?

How to find if it is convergent or not?

Thanks!

Comment: First find the candidates for the limit. They must satisfy $z = \sqrt{i + z}$. Then check how $w \mapsto \sqrt{i + w}$ behaves near those candidates.

Comment: @BabakS. Man ham az hafteye dg miram kelas. Akhe 16om ta hala sabeghe nadashte fek konam. Ba'zia hanooz mosaferatan. In term chia tadris mikonin?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: Gabre khati daram, zabane nakhasosi wa chanta kelas riyazi marbut be reshtehaye modiriyat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints:

$$z=\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i+\ldots}}=\sqrt{i+z}\implies z^2-z-i=0$$

and you're left with a simple complex quadratic to solve

**Note:** Formally , you *first* should prove the sequence $\,\{\sqrt i\,,\,\sqrt{i+\sqrt i}\,,\ldots\}\;$ has a limit. More formally even, one should also choose a branch for the square root...but you can "wave" these in a first approach.